# Progress Bar In AQGridView (Similar to TableView)

Tags: ios

I have an odd problem. I am using an AQGridView which has a method similar to table view controller which I have defined as follows:

```
- (AQGridViewCell *)gridView:(AQGridView *)aGridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IssueCell";

    AQGridViewCell *cell = (AQGridViewCell *)[gridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IssueCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [[AQGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:self.gridViewCellContent.frame
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.gridViewCellContent];

        cell.selectionStyle = AQGridViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    IssueCell *content = (IssueCell *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    //This model object contains the title, picture, and date information
    IssueModel *m = (IssueModel *)[self.issues objectAtIndex:index];

    //If we have already downloaded the file, set the alpha to 1
    if ([m hasPdfBeenDownloaded])
    {
        content.downloadIcon.hidden = YES;
        content.imageView.alpha = 1;
        content.progressView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        if (m.pdfDownloadRequest && m.pdfDownloadRequest.isExecuting)
        {
            content.downloadIcon.hidden = YES;
            content.imageView.alpha = .2;    
            content.progressView.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            content.downloadIcon.hidden = NO;
            content.imageView.alpha = .2;    
            content.progressView.hidden = YES;            
        }
    }

    content.title.text = m.title;
    // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
    if (!m.coverImageIcon)
    {
        if (self.gridView.dragging == NO && self.gridView.decelerating == NO)
        {
            [self startIconDownload:m forIndex:index];
        }

        content.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grid_cell_loading.png"];                

    }
    else
    {
        content.imageView.image = m.coverImageIcon;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

[image: IssueCell]

My problem is since cells are reused, I lose the correct progress indication and updating of it. I am using ASIHTTP as follows:

```
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:model.issuePdfUrl];
        request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ic, @"cell", model, @"model", nil];
        model.pdfDownloadRequest = request;
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDownloadDestinationPath:mediaPath];
        [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:ic.progressView];
        [request startAsynchronous];
```

The problem I am having is when I scroll down and then scroll backup, I lose the progressView I used to have as a reusable cell is used.

What is the correct way to do this so I don't lose the progress view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you bind progressView to a cell (first one, for example), then you scroll to a second cell, it is being created. Then third. This third possibly reuses first cell. But progressBar is not recreated, you reuse it.

So you have one progressBar but two ASIHTTPRequests that point to it. That's not very good.

What can I suggest? Well. You can update link of downloadProgressDelegate with the progressBar during gridView:cellForItemAtIndex: call. That is more ok path. You also can remove reusability of cells. That might help but is less ok and can cause problems (for example memory leaks) in the future.

Another way is to make some single method that gets all the progress messages. And uses these messages to map progress data to a grid model.

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing changing the downloadProgressDelegate